# PHP session extension does not consider global variables

Tags: php, session, global-variables

I am currently getting the error:

> Warning: Unknown: Your script possibly
>   relies on a session side-effect which
>   existed until PHP 4.2.3. Please be
>   advised that the session extension
>   does not consider global variables as
>   a source of data, unless
>   register_globals is enabled. You can
>   disable this functionality and this
>   warning by setting
>   session.bug_compat_42 or
>   session.bug_compat_warn to off,
>   respectively in Unknown on line 0

I believe it has something to do with the following code (since that is when I started noticing it):

```
session_start();                         // Open sessions
$remember_alert = $_SESSION['alert'];   // Remember session alert
session_unset();                         // Unset all data in session
session_destroy();                     // Kill empty session
session_start();                         // Re-open session
$_SESSION['alert'] = $remember_alert;   // Recall session alert
```

This is code on the logoff.php page of a CMS I am building and is used to clear all session info except the alert variable. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unless you are using `register_globals`, you *should not* call [`session_unset`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php).  It is no longer needed.

Comment: You can disable the warning/behavior with these settings: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.bug-compat-42

Comment: @Charles I am unclear as to why I wouldn't use session_unset to log someone off the site. The docs don't say anything about it being deprecated: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

Comment: @cbh, `session_unset` "frees all session variables currently registered."  One "registers" a session variable via [`session_register`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php), which is full of warnings, caveats, and a big fat "deprecated in 5.3."  I wonder why they chose not to deprecate `_unset`. If you aren't registering global variables as part of the session -- and you'd *damn well not be* in this day and age -- then you have no need whatsoever to use `_unset`.  `session_destroy` already "destroys all of the data associated with the current session," which is your goal.

Comment: @Charles Thank you for the info, definitely not using register_globals. Is there an issue with not deleting the SESSIONID since destroy doesn't seem to handle that?

Comment: The session id comes in as a cookie (usually), and it's checked for whenever you call `session_start`.  Because that id data still exists, the session code will try and use it.  Consider using [`session_regenerate_id`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) during login and logout if you're worried about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Hi, I had the same problem, and in my
> case it was here $arrFormData and here
> $_SESSION['arrFormData'] The thing is
> having the same variable name. In my
> case it happened on a $_GET  array,
> but I guess it should be similar. Give
> it a try on renaming the  $arrFormData
> variable to something else and let us
> know if it worked.

[Source](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41540#1292267281).

It is because somewhere you have the same variable name as the key of your `$_SESSION` global.

#### Example

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['a'] = 1;
$a = 1;
```

You can disable the error by turning `session.bug_compat_42` off in your `php.ini` or using `ini_set()`.